# Micrometer-springboot: Hikaricp , Tomcat and jdbc metrics are not exported to DataDog

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, datadog, micrometer, spring-micrometer

Hikaricp , Tomcat and jdbc metrics are not being exported to DataDog

we have setup springboot app to push the metrics to datadoghq, it does export 60 metrics, however the metrics like hikaricp, tomcat and jdbc are missing.

hikaricp, tomcat and jdbc - these mertics are listed under `/actuator/metrics` endpoint, but not exported to datadog.

```
springBootVersion = '2.3.3.RELEASE'
springCloudVersion = 'Hoxton.SR7'
implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-datadog:latest.release'
```

Is there any additional settings required to push hikaricp, tomcat and jdbc metrics ?

Comment: I found the issue, I have another LoggingMeterRegistry as primary, that was stopping additional metrics to be exported to datadogmeter registry.  If I make DatadogMeterRegistry as the primary one, LoggingMeterRegistry do not log tomacat, hikari and jdbc metrics. is there any way I can export all metrics and log to console using LoggingMeterRegistry

Comment: Don't make either a primary. By default a 'CompositeRegistry' should be the primary and the other two will be delegated to.

Comment: if I don,t make it one as primary, it complains that there are two qualifying beans: ```Parameter 0 of method webMvcMetricsFilter in org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsAutoConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
 - getDatadogMeterRegistry: 
 - loggingMeterRegistry:```

Comment: That is strange since actuator include `CompositeMeterRegistryConfiguration` which is autoconfigured.  You can manually create a composite registry and manually add your other registries to it if you like. (I see you did that in your answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This did the trick : Thanks to @MarkBramnik

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    CompositeMeterRegistry compositeMeterRegistry(DatadogMeterRegistry datadogMeterRegistry, LoggingMeterRegistry loggingMeterRegistry) {
        CompositeMeterRegistry compositeMeterRegistry = new CompositeMeterRegistry();
        compositeMeterRegistry.add(datadogMeterRegistry);
        compositeMeterRegistry.add(loggingMeterRegistry);
        return compositeMeterRegistry;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Usually metrics exposed to `/actuator/metrics` are sent to the metrics system like datadog.

You can try to check what exactly gets sent to datadog by examining the source code of [DatadogMeterRegistry](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/implementations/micrometer-registry-datadog/src/main/java/io/micrometer/datadog/DatadogMeterRegistry.java)

Put a breakpoint in the publish method and see what gets sent, or, alternatively set the logger of the class to "trace" so that it will print the information that gets sent to the datadog (line 131 in the linked source code).

Another possible direction to check is usage of filters (see [MeterFilter](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.micrometer/micrometer-core/1.0.3/io/micrometer/core/instrument/config/MeterFilter.html)) that can filter out some metrics.

Comment: Thanks for responding, yes I did inspect and also enabled TRACE, it did send only 60 metrics.  I found the issue, I have another LoggingMeterRegistry as primary, that was stopping additional metrics to be exported to datadogmeter registry.

Comment: If I make DatadogMeterRegistry as the primary one, LoggingMeterRegistry do not log tomacat, hikari and jdbc metrics.  is there any way I can export all metrics and log to console using LoggingMeterRegistry ?

Comment: It sounds like the registries are not initialized properly... Aren't you relying on spring boot and only provide dependencies and letting spring boot to configure everything for you? What is primary registry? Could you llease share the configurarion? In general micrometer uses CompositeMeterRegistry to handle the situation  with multiple registries, so you won'r need to use primary I guess...

Comment: If I dont make one of as primary the startup fails with this error                ```Parameter 0 of method webMvcMetricsFilter in org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsAutoConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
 - getDatadogMeterRegistry: 
 - loggingMeterRegistry:```.

Comment: You should share the initialization code. In general I believe you should go with Composite Registry as a "primary" one, It will include both Logging and DataDog Registries inside, but from the "whole system" in general the CompositeRegistry is the one to work with.

Comment: I have configuration like this:    ```@Bean
    @Primary
    public DatadogMeterRegistry getDatadogMeterRegistry(DatadogConfig config) {
        return DatadogMeterRegistry.builder(config).build();
    }```

``` @Bean
    public LoggingMeterRegistry loggingMeterRegistry() {
        LoggingRegistryConfig config = new LoggingRegistryConfig() {
            ....
        return LoggingMeterRegistry.builder(config).build();
    }```

Comment: and in gradle I have this dependency :
```implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-datadog:latest.release'```

Comment: Yes, but why do you have it? Spring boot should "recognize" all the registries automatically (it should be autonfiguration modules with spring.factories and everything). And then it should create a composite registry so that you only need to add the relevant maven dependencies

Comment: I have added LoggingMeterRegistry to log the metrics, without that explicit bean I couldn't log the metrics to console log. not sure if any other way to log without explicitly declaring the bean

Comment: Maybe it doens't have autoconfiguration, I don't really remember... Anyway you should try to use CompositeMeterRegistry as a "primary" registry and LoggingMeterRegistry should be added to the composite with the help of 'add' method (see documentation https://javadoc.io/static/io.micrometer/micrometer-core/1.0.3/index.html?io/micrometer/core/instrument/composite/CompositeMeterRegistry.html)

Comment: Thank you Mark, that did the trick.. thanks a lot!!